# JavaScript Console doesn't have correct value

Tags: javascript, variables, console

I was goofing around when I decided to try to show a varaible on the console. this is my JS

```
test = 8888888888888888888;
console.log(test)
```

however, on the console, this was shown:

[image: number on console]

Why did 8888888888888888888 go to 8888888888888889000?

Answer (score 3):

The number is larger than the largest value that can be represented exactly in a double-precision floating point value. Modern runtimes expose a constant on the Number constructor with the maximum value (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`). The value is `9007199254740991`.